# В написании телеграмм бота, возникает ошибка

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу на python, библиотека: pyTelegramBotAPI.
Вот код:

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

возникает ошибка:

```
2020-01-26 16:18:33,957 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectionError occurred, args=(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None)),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Пробовали читать [тут](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/0.3.0/)?

Comment: Там не говорится про эту ошибку

Comment: Если ты в России, то скорее всего это из-за блокировки телеграма. Юзай прокси